# Anchor Links/Bookmarks in EPiserver

Tags: html, episerver

I'm using EPiserver to add content to my website and am trying to set up anchor links/bookmarks on the page. Using the "id" attribute like so:

```
<li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
<p id="login"><strong>Login</strong></p>
```

does not create a bookmark I can link to. I also tried placing blank `<a>` tags in front of the text with the id="login" inside `<a>`. No dice.

Using the "name" attribute is apparently not possible with Episerver; each time I create markup similar to the following:

```
<li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
<p name="login"><strong>Login</strong></p>
```

-OR-

```
<p><strong><a name="login">Login</a></strong></p>
```

Episerver just deletes the name attribute after I close its HTML editor. I've done a little research and Epi is supposed to have a tool to create an anchor link, but it's nowhere to be found in my tool menu.
Per w3schools.com, the 'name' attribute in `<a>` is no longer supported in HTML 5, and use of 'id' attribute for bookmarks is preferred. I can't use either attributes in Episerver and there's no tool that I can see that creates bookmarks.

So, my question is: is it possible to create anchor links at all in Episerver, and if it is, how does one create them using raw HTML? I want to skip using a tool if possible. Thanks everybody.

Comment: I have no knowledge of Episerver, and I have no solution, but I do need to say that you just can't slap a `name` attribute on any old start tag. `<p name="login">` is simply invalid and won't do anything at all. Now `<a name="login">` is another matter: although it's no longer part of the official HTML definition (and it would fail validation), it's still supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're missing tools (buttons) in your editor, you probably just need to add them by modifying the property settings for XHTML properties through admin mode. Through there you'll be able to set which buttons should appear in TinyMCE.

What do you mean by "does not create a bookmark I can link to"? Is the markup changed once the page is saved?

Comment: Thanks Ted. I was able to get anchor links working by using the target="_self" attribute in the <a> tags. To answer your question, "does not create a bookmark I can link to" referred to creating jump-links (anchor links that jumped down to a specific spot on the page). And yes, EPiserver deleted the "name" attributes and other, specific markup when I exited the HTML editor.

Comment: If needed you can add additional elements and/or attributes to the TinyMCE config, to avoid them being removed when saving.